# How to SET NOCOUNT ON in SQL CE using ADO.NET?

Tags: ado.net, c#-3.0, compact-framework, sql-server-ce, windows-ce

I want to set nocount on in Windows CE application which uses SQL CE. 
Normally I would write a sproc and set nocount in it but SQL CE does not support sprocs.

**Is it possible to suppress COUNT in ADO.NET SqlCeConnection or SqlCeCommand ?**

Windows CE 6.0 CF.NET 3.5 SQL CE 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible, there is not SET NOCOUNT in SQL Compact - what problem are you trying to solve?